# Отследить отключение клиента sys/socket.h

Tags: c++, c, сокет

Как мне отследить отключение клиентского сокета, если он не вызвал функцию `close`(не закрыл соединение), а просто отключился, например, из-за потери интернета?

Я циклично вызываю функцию `recv`, и, если клиентский сокет закрыл соединение, то возвращается ноль. Но что делать, если у клиента просто пропало соединение? Можно ли сделать так, чтобы функция `recv`/`read` вернула значение(`-1`) при потере соединения? Если что, она просто не завершается.

Я пробовал настраивать опцию `SO_RCVTIMEO`, но она влияет не только на `recv`/`read`, но и на `accept`. Ещё думал создавать отдельный поток, но не уверен, что это правильно.

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Она и так должна вернуть ошибку после таймаута.

Comment: @user7860670, могу ли я сократить таймаут?

Comment: Да, можно воспользоваться опцией SO_RCVTIMEO или через глобальные настройки типа tcp_keepalive_time

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо

Comment: Вызывайте setsockopt с SO_RCVTIMEO для сокета, получаемого из accept (или  используйте poll/select с таймаутом и сами запоминайте время последней активности для каждого сокета)

Comment: @avp, большое спасибо, заработало. Буду использовать блокирующий сокет с setsockopt. Но потом может быть перейду на poll/select. Можете в ответ записать, я отмечу, как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывайте setsockopt с SO_RCVTIMEO для сокета, получаемого из accept.

Или используйте poll/select с таймаутом и сами запоминайте время последней активности для каждого сокета.